# Using PhantomJS in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, poltergeist

I would like to use PhantomJS as part of my main application lifecycle to take screenshots of a remote URL submitted by the user.

I'm familiar with using [Poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) in conjunction with Capybara/Rspec. But how would I go about initializing the `page` object manually?

Comment: Are you looking to use PhantomJS directly, Poltergeist w/PhantomJS, or Capybara with Poltergeist and PhantomJS - your question doesn't make it very clear since `page` is generally a Capybara session but you're asking to use PhantomJS

Comment: Whichever works. I would initialize the capybara session if it lets me use poltergeist driver to take screenshot of the remote page. The important distinction is that I will be initializing it in model/controller as opposed to the test suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initialize a capybara session in your app you can just do something like

```
session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
```

( as documented [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-sessions-manually)) and then rather than using `page` just call Capybara methods on `session`. One thing to note is that if you're going to test the app with Capybara too you will probably want to register a separate driver for the app and testing - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#configuring-and-adding-drivers .  Also since Capybaras config is not thread-safe changing any of Capybaras setting would potentially affect both the test session and the in app session.

Answer (score 2):

A far better solution may be to setup [a separate `Node.js` service which runs `phantom.js`](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) - in fact there are quite a few projects that provide [a ready made screen capture webserver / console command](http://phantomjs.org/related-projects.html).

Capybara is a testing tool and invoking a javascript runtime via ruby adds tons of overhead as well as not being thread-safe. The fact that it is not designed to be run in production is also a pretty big concern.

Instead you would simply call your screenshot service via HTTP or by running a shell command from Ruby.

Answer (score -1):

I really like phantomjs in Rails app.

My suggest are using:

```
watir (https://github.com/watir/watir)
phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org/download.html)
```

You can take a screen shot very easy by using follow this: http://watir.github.io/docs/screenshots/

And if you want to use Page, i thinks you should see PageObject in here: https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/Page-Objects